# jOOQ 3.16 fetch one to one

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, jooq

I want to fetch a DTO as follows:

```kotlin
data class CartItemDto(
    val id: UUID
    val product: ProductDTO 
)
```

The only way I can currently achieve is is by doing two separate queries and then combining those two results into the data class above, but I want to do everything in one jOOQ query. Multiset is not an option and whenever we use `jsonObject` in a custom `field`, it won't work.

The only examples I can find on the internet are for DTO's with lists:

```kotlin
data class CartItemDto(
    val id: UUID
    val product: List<ProductDto> 
)
```

**Extra information**

ProductDto:

```kotlin
data class ProductDto(
    val id: UUID
    val title: String
)
```

Current query:

```kotlin
databaseRepository.getConnection()
                .select(CART_ITEM.CART_ID,
                        row(
                            PRODUCT.ID,
                        ).mapping(::ProductDto))
                .from(CART_ITEM)
                .join(PRODUCT)
                .on(PRODUCT.ID.eq(CART_ITEM.PRODUCT_ID))
                .fetch(Records.mapping(::CartItemDto))
```

But this will only work if I make the data class fields nullable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jOOQ way to map to that `data class` is to use [nested records](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/nested-records/), e.g.

```kotlin
ctx.select(PRODUCT.ID, row(PRODUCT.A, PRODUCT.B, ...).mapping(::ProductDTO))
   .from(PRODUCT)
   .fetch(Recods.mapping(::DTO)) // Your data class, whatever it's called
```

This is the type safe and recommended way. Starting from jOOQ 3.17, you can even [project the entire `T` table as a nested record](https://www.jooq.org/doc/dev/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/tables-as-selectfield/), e.g.

```kotlin
ctx.select(PRODUCT.ID, PRODUCT.mapping(::ProductDTO))
   .from(PRODUCT)
   .fetch(Recods.mapping(::DTO)) // Your data class, whatever it's called
```

Alternatively, you can use the classic approach using reflection and nested column aliases:

```kotlin
ctx.select(
        PRODUCT.ID,
        PRODUCT.A.as("product.a"),
        PRODUCT.B.as("product.b"))
   .from(PRODUCT)
   .fetchInto(DTO::class.java) // Your data class again
```

But I recommend using the type safe approach instead, which also works well along with `MULTISET`.

Comment: I've updated my question. It still won't work, because the fields need to be optional, but this is not what I'm looking for. Also, we don't have jOOQ premium so I believe we cannot use jOOQ 3.17. Any idea when it will release?

Comment: @KittyCat: Yes, you have to make those columns nullable, see the various discussions about nullability on jOOQ and kotlin on the issue tracker and on stack overflow. I don't see why you can't use jOOQ 3.17? But you don't need it, the 3.16 version can work with `row()` just fine. 3.17 will release:.... "eventually"

Comment: Thanks. It works now. Someone recently told me that we needed jOOQ premium for pre-release versions, like jOOQ v3.17. One last question; what is the difference in this case between using a TableRecord and a Record? So in our case CartItemRecord or CartItem (both imported from jOOQ).

Comment: @KittyCat: Ah, I see, yes to access the snapshot builds from here, you need to be licensed: https://www.jooq.org/download/versions. You can build the latest version yourself, from github, though. May I ask you to ask that `TableRecord` vs `Record` question in a new question? I'd like to elaborate more than is possible in the comments, so others can profit.

Comment: I've made a new question for this regard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72139237/jooq-difference-between-record-and-tablerecord