# jOOQ difference between Record and TableRecord

Tags: jooq

I would like to know what the difference is between a jOOQ `Record` and a `TableRecord`. So for example a `User` and a `UserRecord`. I can see that it has something to do with the actual nullability of a certain table, but why does everyone use the `TableRecord` and when should I ever use the normal `Record`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a manual page about literally your question: [`Record` vs. `TableRecord`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/record-vs-tablerecord/). In short:

- `Record` is the generic super type of all jOOQ records.
- `TableRecord` is a specific type of record, which can be associated with a table in your schema. This type is typically extended by [code generation output](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/)

> So for example a `User` and a `UserRecord`

This might be a different question. jOOQ's code generator produces these artifacts for each table, depending on your configuration:

- [The `Table`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-tables/) (e.g. `User`). You use this to construct type safe jOOQ queries
- [The `TableRecord`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-records/) (e.g. `UserRecord`). You can use this to [simplify some CRUD operations](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/)
- [The POJO](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-pojos/) (e.g. `User`, but in a different package). You can use this to map results to simple POJOs

Comment: Yes, I know, but why does jOOQ generate two classes one User and one UserRecord, and which one should be used? You asked me to ask this question in a new thread and so I did.

Comment: @KittyCat: Well, I'm not sure if you asked 2 questions (`Record` vs `TableRecord` and `User` vs `UserRecord`), or if that was just a misunderstanding about what the generated objects were... The way you phrased this question, it's 2 questions in one.